# Excel VBA: writing to mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I would like to write a macro in Excel that will write to a mysql database. Can someone please get me started on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can connect to MySQL with a connection string and ADO:

```
''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;" _
& "User=root;Password=pw;Option=3;"

cn.Open strCon
```

You can also use DSN with a connection to Excel using the Jet driver:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

''Not the best way to get the name, just convenient for notes
strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

''For this to work, you must create a DSN and use the name in place of 
''DSNName
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DSN=DSNName;].NameOfMySQLTable " _
& "Select AnyField As NameOfMySQLField FROM [Sheet1$];"

cn.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: thanks remou, can u show me how i would execute the sql statement>?

Comment: I have added some notes, but I do not have MySQL installed on this PC at the moments, so I am working from my notes. The above suggestions are by no means the only ways to go about this.

Comment: @Remou: Hey I get the error : `Compiler Error: User-defined types not defined` on line `Dim cn As ADODB.Connection` What could be wrong?

Comment: @Parth Add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library - from the code window choose Tools->References and tick the relevant line.

Comment: Thanks Remou for your quick reply. What is the `DSNName` and `NameOfMySQLField`? What should I write in place of that?

Comment: @PARTH If you have a DSN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html), it DSNName the name you gave that, if not the whole bracketed section `[ODBC;DSN=DSNName;]` can contain a suitable connection string (http://connectionstrings.com). NameOfMySQLField  is just that, the name of the relevant field in your MySQL table.

Comment: +1 `strSQL = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DSN=DSNName;].NameOfMySQLTable " _
& "Select AnyField As NameOfMySQLField FROM [Sheet1$];"` this is _slick_ ... i never knew this.

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a mysql database is no different to writing to any other database.

You'd create an ADODB.Connection object, .Open it with an [appropriate connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) and use the .Execute method (or ADODB.Command) to execute sql.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx for more information.

You'd have to a have a mysql access driver installed (ODBC or OLEDB) and reference the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 from your vba project.