# Excel VBA: Query a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, data-structures, excel, database-connection, vba

I am looking for an example of how to query a MySQL database using Excel VBA.

I am able to use ***Data \ From Other Sources \ From Microsoft Query*** to import data from the db, but what I am actually looking for is a way not to import it to a spreadsheet directly, but rather to a data structure in VBA for further manipulation before I output the result to the spreadsheet. How can I do this?

Comment: As in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821718/excel-vba-writing-to-mysql-database/2821911#2821911 ?

Comment: @Remou - not quite, I was looking for an example how to query and receive the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to connect:

```
conMySQL.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & "SERVER=" & server & ";" & " DATABASE=" & database & ";" & "UID=" & login_user & ";PWD=" & password & "; OPTION=3; PORT=" & port & ";Connect Timeout=20;"

    'open the connection
    conMySQL.Open
```

then to query:

```
strSQL = "SELECT x FROM some_table"
MySQL.Query (strSQL)

With rsTemporary
      Do Until .EOF
          recordCount = recordCount + 1
          some_variable = ![supcode]
          rsTemporary.MoveNext
      Loop
End With
        MySQL.closeCon
```

Comment: Which are the data types of MySQL and conMySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & password _
& ";OPTION=3" '

Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `ID`=" & ID & ";" 
rs1.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
With Worksheets("Main").Cells(1, 1)
.ClearContents
.CopyFromRecordset rs1
End With
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```