# Excel inserts into database

Tags: sql, excel

I have in excel some values(more than 200) in this format

```
PlayerId,Amount1,Amount2,Amount3
```

So how can i insert those values in some sql table with excel?
How to write INSERT formula in Excel that will insert that values in my sql table(named TABLE1)

so i want to have something like 
`INSERT INTO TABLE1(PlayerId,Amount1,Amount2,Amount3) VALUES(here put values from excel)`

Comment: Why don't you use SQL wizard to import those data?

Comment: Already find the solution on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: writing to mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821718/excel-vba-writing-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this on another CELL and them drag it down to all the rows

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO TABLE1(PlayerId,Amount1,Amount2,Amount3)  values(",A1,",",B1,",",C1,",",D1,")")
```